# adding NSSubmenu item in NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem

I want to add a drop down menu in one of the entries in the NSMenu Item. (eg. If you click on the Battery indicator on Finder bar, it has an option for Show->Icon,Time,Percentage).
Now I add a MenuItem using the following code:

```
         menuItem = [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Start"
        action:@selector(start:) keyEquivalent:@""]; 
        [menuItem setTarget:self];
```

How do I add a submenu Item with this drop down list ? Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

This is how I add a submenu to an NSMenu item:

```
NSMenuItem *mainItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
[mainItem setTitle:@"Main item"];

NSMenu *submenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
[submenu addItemWithTitle:@"Sub item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];

[mainItem setSubmenu:submenu];
```

Answer (score -3):

Got it working. Created a NSPopuButton with contents from an array and then used that here.

```
[menu setSubmenu:[(NSPopupButton *array) menu] forItem:menuItem];
```

Comment: 1. That isn't valid syntax. 2. Why did you name your pop-up button “array”? And why are you casting it? 3. You probably shouldn't put the same menu in two different places. Make a copy of the pop-up button's menu and use that as the submenu. Or, if you're not actually using the pop-up button, why are you creating one?